# how to make chat for iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift

how to make chat for ios  ?
I need to make chat when user A chat with user B. I can use server between this users.  How to make that  user B will know that user A send him a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using two possible ways.

1.) Using **Socket.IO** communication for web-api on both client and server side 
 As socket is a two way communication
see this

http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

http://socket.io/demos/chat/

This will work best when application is in running state

2.) You use  **APNS** for receiving notification when app is in background or foreground both states.

Simple is that when **App A** has to send message a web-api is called from application and on a response web-server send push notification to **APP B** and vice virsa.

see this http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2

I hope this would help.